# Updating the All Subscriber List when submitting through a Custom Subscription Center

Tags: ampscript, api, soap, unsubscriber, publicationlist

I need help figuring out the process of updating the All Subscriber/publications list when a subscriber changes their subscription status through a custom subscription center that I'm hosting on a Cloudpage.

I already have successfully implemented an update a data extension when the form is submitted, but I am having trouble figuring out where to turn in terms of triggering API calls, and what those API calls will even look like in the first place, because I am new to writing API calls. I can post the code for the center, but I haven't even really tried getting the calls to work because I really just don't know where to start. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this help page on creating a [Custom Profile Center with AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm).

> Your custom profile center allows you to both manage information
>   inside your Marketing Cloud account and use that information to
>   conduct triggered sends as confirmation of more or changed information
>   in a particular profile. The automation allows the user to keep their
>   information up to date without involving more effort from your team.
>   This profile center also allows you to review tracking information
>   inside Marketing Cloud for analysis and appropriate action.

Comment: My question is, how does that happen? Where do I set up this automation, and what does that look like in the code?

Comment: You can set it up on the custom subscription center using AMPscript or use an automation that extracts, file transfers, and imports into All Subscribers

Comment: You are not answering the question haha, I know that I CAN set it up, but I have no idea how to even begin to implement it or what it looks like in the code itself.

Comment: @DaveFroop The link provided has the actual code. I will urge you to read up on the basics on AMPscript and Marketing Cloud in general

Comment: I've been through that page several times, it seems that I am missing a key part of this puzzle though.

Comment: This may help: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createTriggeredSend.htm